Urolithin A for Alzheimer's?
Recently there have been items in the general media about a study carried out at the University of Copenhagen and the American Institute of aging concerning some possibly beneficial effects of the agent urolithin A in helping the brain fight against Alzheimer's.
Now urolithin A is not found naturally but is a metabolised form of agents found in fruits and nuts such as pomegranate and walnuts.
Urolithin A is not a new agent and has been used in treatment of other conditions, but its reportedly beneficial effects for neurological issues was apparently only noticed recently.
Further information about availability in pill form, degree of effectiveness, and possible side effects would be appreciated.  I have no training in either chemistry or biology, therefore it is hard for me to gauge the following:
Question. How effective would a treatment with Urolithin A be likely to be for an Alzheimer patient?

This isn't a question; it's a request for people to do research for you. That's not how SE works. What you need to do is some research on your own and then if there are things you don't understand you can [edit] this to form a specific question.

I’m voting to close this post because it isn't a question.

Alzheimer's disease has a huge impact on patients, their families, and is extremely expensive for governments and insurance companies. If there is good evidence of efficacy for any treatment for AD, it will not be kept a secret.

@BryanKrause, this is very recent research and it has only been done on mice, if I understood it correctly.  Certainly if good evidence of efficacy for humans emerges, somebody will become famous (and rich).  But my question is how plausible such a scenario would be.  I am not too familiar with the history of this issue; for example, if similar claims (with other agents) have been made before and turned out not to lead too far, this would decrease the likelihood of a dramatic breakthrough for a urolithin A treatment.  P.S. Thanks for reopening the question.

We can't predict the outcome of trials for a new drug. Anyone who could do that would rule the world's pharmaceutical industries. Are you perhaps looking for general stats. relating to success percentage for drugs selected for trial? Please clarify the question if so.

General stats for success of drugs in general would be less interesting than general stats for success of drugs used for treatment of Alzheimer.  Notice that what is interesting about t his particular agent is that it does not battle the onset of the bad cells, but rather helps the brain itself fight against the bad cells.  I had the impression that this seems to be a new approach, but again I have very little experience with the history of the question, and was hoping that some users here might have more.  @JiminyCricket.

Well, so far the stats for success of drugs for treatment of AD is 0% in that we have no drug that prevents or treats AD; there are a couple drugs that help a bit with symptoms temporarily, that's it. Is that useful? It's also not an answer to the question asked but a different question you added in a comment.

Have there been agents claimed to help with AD in laboratory tests with mice that turned out not to be helpful with humans?  @BryanKrause

Separate question, unless you want to edit this one. Remember we're not a discussion site (unfortunately).

@MikhailKatz Yes, probably thousands of them. Tons of research in this area plus https://xkcd.com/882/

@BryanKrause :-)  But this particular experiment is not based on anecdotal evidence unlike the XKCD.  It seems to be solid research (on mice).

The XKCD comic has nothing to do with anecdotal evidence, it's depicting the ordinary scientific process and the concept of statistical significance. With a p-value threshold of 0.05, 5% studies attempted with an agent that has no effect at all will show a promising result. Then that doesn't count things that actually do work in mice that don't work in humans, work to treat AD models that are not actually AD because mice do not ever get actual AD, etc. With many thousands of different AD studies in mice, many treatments will show promise. None actually work yet.

Try a search like https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C50&q=reduces+alzheimer%27s+disease+in+mice&btnG=
